# Multiline items in a custom list?

Tags: lists, indentation

I have the following custom list for generating dates on a syllabus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}
\newdateformat{syldate}{\twodigit{\THEMONTH}/\twodigit{\THEDAY}
\,(\shortdayofweekname
{\THEDAY}{\THEMONTH}{\THEYEAR})}
\newenvironment{schedule}
  {\par\syldate\renewcommand{\item}{\par
    \stepcounter{mycntr}\ifnum\value{mycntr}>2\relax
      \setcounter{mycntr}{0}\AdvanceDate[3]
    \else
      \AdvanceDate[2]
    \fi\today\quad}
  }{\par}
\SetDate[01/09/2014]
\newcounter{mycntr}

\begin{document}

\begin{schedule} % My custom environment with problematic behavior

\item Topic \\ Assigned Reading

\item Topic \\ Assigned Reading

\end{schedule}

\begin{itemize} % Desired behavior
    \item Topic \\ Assigned Reading
    \item Topic \\ Assigned Reading
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Whenever I try to move the second part of an item to a new line, it aligns itself with the item label rather than the first line of the item. Itemize does what I want by default. How do I build that behavior into my custom list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't plan to have lists and paragraphs in the “Assigned readings”, you can go with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}
\newdateformat{syldate}{%
  \twodigit{\THEMONTH}/\twodigit{\THEDAY}%
  \,(\shortdayofweekname
  {\THEDAY}{\THEMONTH}{\THEYEAR})%
}
\newlength{\datelength}
\newenvironment{schedule}
  {\par
   \settowidth{\datelength}{00/00\,(Wed)\quad}%
   \renewcommand{\item}{%
     \par\hangindent=\datelength\noindent
     \stepcounter{mycntr}\ifnum\value{mycntr}>2\relax
       \setcounter{mycntr}{0}\AdvanceDate[3]%
    \else
       \AdvanceDate[2]%
    \fi
    \makebox[\datelength][l]{\today}%
  }%
  \syldate
  }
  {\par}
\SetDate[01/09/2014]
\newcounter{mycntr}

\begin{document}

\begin{schedule} % My custom environment with problematic behavior

\item Topic \\ Assigned Reading

\item Topic \\ Assigned Reading

\item Topic \\ Assigned Reading

\item Topic \\ Assigned Reading

\end{schedule}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, a better implementation is with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}
\newdateformat{syldate}{%
  \twodigit{\THEMONTH}/\twodigit{\THEDAY}%
  \,(\shortdayofweekname
  {\THEDAY}{\THEMONTH}{\THEYEAR})%
}
\newlength{\datelength}
\newcommand\topic[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mycntr}%
  \ifnum\value{mycntr}>2\relax
    \setcounter{mycntr}{0}\AdvanceDate[3]%
  \else
    \AdvanceDate[2]%
  \fi
  \item[\today]#1\\
}
\newenvironment{schedule}
  {\syldate
   \settowidth{\datelength}{00/00\,(Wed)\quad}%
   \enumerate[leftmargin=\datelength,labelsep=0pt,labelwidth=\datelength,align=left]
  }
  {\endenumerate}
\SetDate[01/09/2014]
\newcounter{mycntr}

\begin{document}

\begin{schedule}

\topic{Topic} Assigned Reading

\topic{Topic} Assigned Reading

\topic{Topic} Assigned Reading

\topic{Topic} Assigned Reading

\end{schedule}

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer a `\topic` command instead of abusing `\item` so that the appearance of the topic title can be customized at will by just acting on the definition of `\topic`.

Vertical spacings can be customized with `enumitem` features. Note that `showframe` is used here just to show the text block margins.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The disparity of indent arises from the fact that the 1st line indent is due to `\parindent`, which does not carry to successive lines.  The parameter for carrying an indent to successive lines is `\leftskip`.  I would significantly rewrite the approach (perhaps using a `list` environment, but to quickly achieve what you ask, I merely inserted this line

```
\leftskip=\parindent\relax\parindent=0pt\relax
```

at the beginning of your `schedule` environment.  It has the effect of using the current value of `\parindent` for the `\leftskip` for that invocation of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}
\newdateformat{syldate}{\twodigit{\THEMONTH}/\twodigit{\THEDAY}
\,(\shortdayofweekname
{\THEDAY}{\THEMONTH}{\THEYEAR})}
\newenvironment{schedule}
  {\leftskip=\parindent\relax\parindent=0pt\relax
    \par\syldate\renewcommand{\item}{\par
    \stepcounter{mycntr}\ifnum\value{mycntr}>2\relax
      \setcounter{mycntr}{0}\AdvanceDate[3]
    \else
      \AdvanceDate[2]
    \fi\today\quad}
  }{\par}
\SetDate[01/09/2014]
\newcounter{mycntr}

\begin{document}

\begin{schedule} % My custom environment with problematic behavior

\item Topic \\ Assigned Reading

\item Topic \\ Assigned Reading

\end{schedule}

\begin{itemize} % Desired behavior
    \item Topic \\ Assigned Reading
    \item Topic \\ Assigned Reading
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Note that the way you have set things, the `schedule` environment is indented by a value of `\parindent`.  That can be removed by setting, in my MWE, the value of `\leftskip` to 0pt, rather than to `\parindent`.